# What is causing "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm receiving the following error:

**Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2227 of includes/database/database.inc).**

I've narrowed it down to this code but I am still able see what is wrong with the code, it worked before but now I am getting this recurring error.

```
case 'field_home' :
$tids =  field_get_items('node', $node, $key, $node->language);
$terms = taxonomy_term_load_multiple(array(), array('tid' => $tids));
// Gets Field Array Based on Term IDs
$name = array();
foreach($terms as $term){
$name[] = $term->name;}
$return[$key_clean] = $name;
```

Answer (score 3):

Please pass $tids array direct to the function.
E.g:

```
$terms = taxonomy_term_load_multiple($tids);
```

NOTE: Also before passing $tids to the function, please check it is include only tids.
E.g:

$tids should be like $tids = [10,11,12,13,...];

Comment: In addition, the output of field_get_items() is not suitable to be passed into taxonomy_term_load_multiple() without some additional manipulation.

Comment: Yeah right @rooby, I added note in answer.

Comment: @vijay my $tids is outputting a multi value the tids are in there but ther is excess data , how could I change to output = [10,11,12,13,...];
thx!

Comment: something like array_column($tids, 'tid')  perhaps ^